# asp .net gridview , i want the page to appear even if the total pages is one

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working on an asp .ne project and a have a gridview, According to the users selection the same gridview databounds different amount of data. Sometimes it has 10 pages and sometimes just one. When the pages total is just one then the pager row does not appear, But onRowDataBound event i have an if statement that checks if there is a PagerRow and it successfuly pass it. How can i appear the pager row even if the total pages are just one?.

It passes the following statement or RowDataBound event

```
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
    {
        e.Row.Visible = true;
    }
```

Any help pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the OnPreRender Event-Handler and then add the following code:

```
 protected void MyGridView_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
          GridViewRow pagerRow = (GridViewRow) this.BottomPagerRow;

          if(pagerRow != null && pagerRow.Visible == false)
          pagerRow.Visible = true;
 }
```

Comment: I get the following error Error 28 'newQuestion.MyGridView_PreRender(object, System.EventArgs)' is inaccessible due to its protection level p.s the gridview is in ascx control if it helps you

Comment: Add the key word "protected" before "void"